# Angular 2 create ViewContainerRef on run time

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I’m using  ag-grid and on hover row I would like to display a custom tool-tip component.

In angular 2 we need the ViewContainerRef in order to create dynamic component.

How to create ViewContainerRef on hover row in run time.

Comment: it's not possible, it's created during compilation